# How to specify rtsp authentication credentials on client side with gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0, rtsp-client

The [gstreamer RTSP server](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/) supports basic username-password authentication ([example](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-auth.c)). On the client side, the [gstreamer playbin element](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/playback/playbin.html?gi-language=c) supports playback from an RTSP server, like this:

```
playbin uri=rtsp://127.0.0.1:554/test
```

Is there a way to specify credentials (a username and password) on the client side when connecting to the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `gst-inspect-1.0 rtspsrc`:

```
  user-id             : RTSP location URI user id for authentication
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
  user-pw             : RTSP location URI user password for authentication
                        flags: readable, writable
                        String. Default: null
```

EDIT:
Oh playbin..

Does it not accept user and password from URI? E.g:

```
playbin uri=rtsp://user:password@ip.address/stream
```